# Stein's identity with Normal random variable

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimation, mean, decision-theory

I'm having trouble to understand the Stein's identity in [Theory of point estimation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985026)

> Let $X$ a random variable with density in canonical form given by 
>   $$p(x|\eta)=\exp\Big(\sum \eta_iT_i(x)-A(\eta)\Big)h(x)$$ where $\eta$ 
>   is the natural parameter, and $T(x)$ is some statistic. Take some
>   differentiable function $g$ such that $\mathbb{E}[g'(X)]<\infty$, then
>
> $$\mathbb{E}\left(\left[\frac{h'(X)}{h(X)}+\sum \eta_iT_i'(X)\right]g(X)\right)=-\mathbb{E}[g'(X)] \tag{1}$$

**Example:** If $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then the above expression becomes
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)(X-\mu)]=\sigma^2\mathbb{E}[g'(X)] \tag{2}$$
where $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mu$ if $g(x)=1$ and $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\sigma^2+\mu^2$

Anyone can help me figure out how they reach equation **(2)** from equation **(1)**?

I do not know if I'm letting anything go, but what's the idea behind this lemma? Why would I want to calculate the mean of the expression on the left side in equation **(1)**?

Comment: Stein's Lemma leads to unbiased estimators of differences of risk functions. If the unbiased estimator is positive, then the difference is positive and one can deduce which decision procedure is uniformly better.

Comment: Originally the idea was that for a multivariate normal distribution you shrink the estimate toward a point (including possibly the origin).  This class of estimator is called a James-Stein estimator.  It has also been shown to be an empirical Bayes estimator.  The original idea was due to the late Charles Stein who past away late last year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question,
for the normal density with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ [we have, in order to map it to the  Exponential Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Examples) form,

$$\eta = \frac {\mu}{\sigma}$$
$$ T(x) = \frac {x}{\sigma} \implies T'(x) = \frac {1}{\sigma}$$
$$h(x) = \frac {1}{\sigma}\phi(x/\sigma) \implies h'(x) = h(x) \cdot \left(-\frac{x}{\sigma^2}\right)$$

where $\phi()$ is the standard normal density.

Answer (score 3):

The result is mostly meaningful in the multidimensional case:
$$\mathbb{E}[||X-g(X)X-\mu||^2]=\mathbb{E}[||X-\mu||^2+||g(X)X||^2-2g(X)X^{\text{T}}(X-\mu)]$$implies terms of the form
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^p} g(x)x_i(x_i-\mu_i) \varphi(x-\mu)\,\text{d}x$$
where $\varphi$ is the joint density. An inner integral in this multivariate integral is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)x_i(x_i-\mu_i) \frac{\exp\{-(x_i-\mu_i)^2/2\sigma^2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\,\text{d}x_i=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)x_i\sigma^2\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x_i}\frac{-\exp\{-(x_i-\mu_i)^2/2\sigma^2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\,\text{d}x_i=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sigma^2\frac{\exp\{-(x_i-\mu_i)^2/2\sigma^2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g(x)x_i\,\text{d}x_i=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sigma^2\frac{\exp\{-(x_i-\mu_i)^2/2\sigma^2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\left\{g(x)+x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g(x)\right\}\,\text{d}x_i$$
Therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)X^{\text{T}}(X-\mu)]=\sum_{i=1}^p\mathbb{E}[g(X)+X_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g(X)]=\mathbb{E}[pg(X)+X^{\text{T}}\nabla g(X)]$$
This implies that$$\mathbb{E}[||X-g(X)X-\mu||^2]=\mathbb{E}[||X-\mu||^2]+\mathbb{E}[||g(X)X||^2]-2\sigma^2\mathbb{E}[pg(X)+X^{\text{T}}\nabla g(X)]$$
Therefore, if 
$$||g(x)x||^2-2\sigma^2pg(x)-\sigma^2x^{\text{T}}\nabla g(x)\le 0$$
for all $x$'s the estimator $X-g(X)X$ does better than $X$ for all $\mu$'s